# Perfect Square in an UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an UFD with quotient field $F$. Show that an element $d\in R$ is a square in $R$ if and only if $d$ is a square in $F$.

And then get a counterexample that above statement is not true if $R$ is not UFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is the square of an element in $R$, then $d$ is certainly the square of an element in $F$.

Now suppose $d$ is the square of an element in $F$.  A typical nonzero element in $F$ is a quotient of elements in $R$.  And since every element of $R$ is a product of irreducibles, every element in $F$ is a quotient of products of irreducibles.  In other words, a nonzero element in $F$ is just a product of the form $A^aB^bC^c$ etc. where $A, B, C$ etc. are irreducible members of $R$ and $a, b, c$ etc. are integers.  These latter integers may, of course, be negative.

So what happens if $d$ is the square of an element in $F$?  We have that $d = (A^aB^bC^c$ etc.)$^2$, or $d = A^{2a}B^{2b}C^{2c}$ etc.  Since $d$ is a member of $R$, every power belonging to the irreducibles which compose $d$ (that is, $2a, 2b, 2c$ etc.) must be positive.  But this means that $a, b, c$ etc. must also be positive, meaning that $A^{a}B^{b}C^{c}$ etc. has to be an element of $R$.  Thus $d$ is the square of an element in $R$.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample

Comment: lol maybe.  can you think of any non-UFDs, first of all?

Comment: @Firmino, see my answer. I have a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a counterexample for the case when $R$ is not an UFD: set $R=K[X^2,X^3]$, the ring of polynomials over a field $K$ whose monomial of degree one is missing. Then the field of fractions of $R$ is $F=K(X)$. Now take $X^2\in R$. This is obviously a square in $F$, but there is no $a\in R$ such that $a^2=X^2$ (otherwise $X\in R$, a contradiction).

Comment: Dear @Firmino, now you have also a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Forward direction: If $d$ is a squre in $R$, then $d=c^2$ for some $c\in R$. Thus, $\frac{d}{1}=[\frac{c}{1}]^2$.

Backward direction: Let $\frac{d}{1}=[\frac{r}{s}]^2$. Thus, $s^2d=r^2$. By writing $d,s,r$ as products of irreducibles one can see that the exponents of the irreducibles that appear in the prime factorization of $d$ are even.

Comment: How is that a counterexample?  A counterexample would entail giving an example of an integral domain $R$ with quotient field $K$ such that the square of something in $F$ is in $R$, but is not the square of anything in $R$.  $\mathbb{Z_6}$ isn't an integral domain.

Comment: i was not concentrating

Answer (score 0):

Just as for irrationality proofs in $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ this is an *immediate* consequence of the monic case of the [Rational Root Test (RRT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) which is true in any UFD (or any GCD domain), since the proof uses only Euclid's Lemma $\rm\:(a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\:\Rightarrow\:a\mid c.\:$ In particular, if $\rm\:x^2\! -c,\ c\in R,\:$ has a "rational" root $\rm\:x\in F\:$ then it must be "integral" $\rm\:x\in R\:$ by RRT.

This fails in non-UFD domains, e.g. there are very simple quadratic integer counterexamples:

$\rm\ \ x^2\! = (1\!+\!\sqrt{d})^2\!\in \Bbb Z[2\sqrt{d}]\ $ has root $\rm\ x = 1\!+\!\sqrt{d} = \dfrac{2\!+\!2\sqrt{d}}2\:$ a *proper* fraction over $\rm\:\Bbb Z[2\sqrt{d}]$

**Remark** $\ $ Rings satisfying the monic case of the Rational Root Test are called [integrally closed.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain) Thus the remark above translates as: the usual proof of RRT immediately generalizes to show that UFDs and GCD domains are integrally closed.